# Getting current workspace name as a string in xmonad

Tags: xmonad, haskell

I want to get the currently active tag in xmonad as a string. I've imported the stackset with

```
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
```

I can get get the tag of the currently focused workspace with `W.currentTag`, but it's type is `StackSet i0 l0 a0 s0 sd0 -> i0`

How do I convert this to a string?

Answer (score 1):

`i` is of type http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Core.html#t:WindowSet which is a type alias for `String`.

`currentTag` will evaluate to `String` if you give it a parameter relating to  `StackSet`.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:withWindowSet is what you could use.

So I think you can do: `withWindowSet (pure . currentTag)` this is an expression of type `X String`

---

It's also available here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Util-Loggers.html#v:logCurrent

```
import XMonad.Util.Loggers
logCurrent :: X (Maybe String)
```